# ItemList.js:15 Uncaught TypeError: items.map is not a function

Tags: php, reactjs

I am using React Js as frontend and core Php as backend. I store data through a form in Mysql and then want to display that data in the UI on another page. There is no use of Props .Below is my React js code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Container, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import axios from "axios";

function ItemList() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost/reactphp/items/").then(function (response) {
      setItems(response.data);
      // console.log(items);
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <Container>
      <Row>
     
        {items.map((item, key) => (
          <Col lg="4" sm="6" key={key}>
            <img src={item.image} alt="pic" />
            <h3>{item.name}</h3>
            <span>{item.price}</span>
          </Col>
        ))}
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default ItemList;
```

Below is my Php code.

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
include 'conn.php';
$getData = "SELECT * FROM items";
$result = $conn->query($getData);
$data = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
}
echo json_encode($data);
print_r($data);
?>
```

I tried it almost everywhere but could not get the answer

Comment: add this in php `header('Content-Type: applicatiton/json');`

Answer (score 0):

I think the `print_r($data);` is messing with the return. Just remove it.

```php
<?php
    $myArray = ["foo", "bar"];
    echo json_encode($myArray);
    print_r($myArray);
    
    /**
     * Output an invalid JSON
     * 
        ["foo","bar"]Array
        (
            [0] => foo
            [1] => bar
        )
     *
     */
```